# Dataframe is not aligned properly

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

Im getting data from a rest api, convert it to json and then into a dataframe. I then put that dataframe into a csv file.

The problem is that while it recognizes the column tags correctly, it aligns them 1 to the right because a 0 showed up to the very left.

I know its the count of rows, but how do I stop it from counting OR how would I go about creating one additional column with the "counter" tag.

```
response_dividends = requests.get(
        f"https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/aapl/dividends/quote?token={iex_api}")
response_dividends_parsed = json.loads(response_dividends.text)
df = pd.DataFrame(response_dividends_parsed)
df.to_csv("main_data.csv")
```

the result then looks like this

```
    ,amount,currency,declaredDate,description,exDate,flag,frequency,paymentDate,recordDate,refid,symbol,id,key,subkey,updated
0,0.22,USD,2021-04-15,Sydhnrraas Oeir,2021-04-25,Cash,quarterly,2021-05-12,2021-04-27,2239859,AAPL,NDIDDSEIV,LAAP,2243550,1683800492545
```

the problem is, its not correctly aligned
I opened it in the csv viewer plugin of pycharm and it shows:

[wrong aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9buni.png)

Comment: Please provide either the data you feed to pandas as a `dict` or a runnable `get` request - `iex_api` is missing here, or the actual string you get in `response_dividends.text`. Can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: see Thoms answer below, that solved it for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set index=False, the row names (which is the count of rows) will not be written to your csv file.

```
df.to_csv("main_data.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: @AlexanderSchmitt  Great! Note that you could consider marking my answer as accepted, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I did! Thanks again :) I have a new issue if you want to have a look at it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67384259/python-code-not-executing-until-client-is-started-even-tho-the-print-is-being?noredirect=1#comment119104166_67384259