# Python code not executing until client is started even tho the print() is being executed properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, sockets

I have a problem. When executing the code below, its getting data from a REST API, converting that to JSON and then into a dataframe and putting it into a .csv file. The issue is that when I execute the file, it prints out "server is running" but only when I start the client it puts the Dataframe into the csv file

The client as of now has nothing to do with the dataframe or the csv file

this is the server.py file which I run first, note that api key and IP have been censored

```
import json
import socket
from _thread import *
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv

iex_api = "api key"
host = "server IP"
port = 1234
ThreadCount = 0
decode_format = "utf-8"
encoding_format = encoding="utf-8"

ss = socket.socket()
ss.bind((host, port))
ss.listen(5)

#inital message
print("Server is running")
#update function
response_dividends = requests.get(
        f"https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/aapl/dividends/quote?token={iex_api}")
response_dividends_parsed = json.loads(response_dividends.text)
df = pd.DataFrame(response_dividends_parsed)
df.to_csv("main_data.csv", index=False)


#thread counter and connection handler
while True:
    clientsocket, address = ss.accept()
    ThreadCount = ThreadCount + 1
    print(f"Connected IP: {address}")
    print(f"Thread number: {ThreadCount}")
    clientsocket.send(bytes("connected to server", encoding_format))
```

this is the client.py file that i run after and only THEN the dataframe gets put into the .csv file

```
import socket

host = "server IP"
port = 1234
decode_format = "utf-8"

ss = socket.socket()
ss.connect((host, port))
response = ss.recv(1024)
print(response.decode(decode_format))
```

my questions would be:

why does it execute the print("server is running") immediately, but not the df.to_csv line

note: it doesnt matter if i put the print before or after the df.to_csv line, it completely ignores the line until a client connection has been made

Comment: Try changing this line 

response_dividends = requests.get(
        f"https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/aapl/dividends/quote?token={iex_api}")

to this:

response_dividends = requests.get(
        f"https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/aapl/dividends/quote?token={iex_api}", timeout=1)

Comment: the "timeout=1" doesnt change anything